# OptimisticLockingException with Camunda Service Task

Tags: java, business-process-management, camunda

We're seeing OptimisticLockingExceptions in a Camunda process with the following Scenario:

The process consists of one UserTask followed by one Gateway and one ServiceTask. The UserTask executes

```
runtimeService.setVariable(execId, "object", out);`. 
taskService.complete(taskId);
```

The following ServiceTask uses "object" as input variable (does not modify it) and, upon completion  throws said `OptimisticLockingException`. My problem seems to originate from the fact, that `taskService.complete()` immediately executes the ServiceTask, prior to flushing the variables set in the UserTask.

I've had another, related issue, which occured, when in one UserTask I executed `runtimeService.setVariable(Map<Strong, Boolean>)` and tried to access the members of the Map as transition-guards in a gateway following that UserTask.

I've found the following article: http://forums.activiti.org/content/urgenterror-updated-another-transaction-concurrently which seems somehow related to my issue. However, I'm not clear on the question whether this is (un)wanted behaviour and how I can access a `DelegateExecution`-Object from a UserTask.

Comment: The behavior you describe is not expected. What is the nature of the `out` variable? Is it a complex java object implementing `Serializable`?

Comment: It is a `Serializable` and by now, we are rather certain to have uncovered at least one bug.

Comment: instead of runtimeService.setVariable && taskService.completeTask, consider joining the two calls: taskService.completeTask(id, Map)

Comment: Excellent idea which works in most of our cases, however in one case we need to store variables during execution and prior to task completion. Is there a mechanism for this scenario also?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with [this gist](https://gist.github.com/meyerdan/7335610). What is different in your case? Can you provide a failing testcase?

Comment: We think, we found it (although we do not have a contained testcase). We were using a Tasklistener, listening for Task-creation. Within this TaskListener we also made a call to `runtimeService.getVariables()`. This was the culprit, changing it to `delegateTask.getVariables()` solves the issue. I will check, whether I can get a contained Testcase to reproduce this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long and cumbersome search we think, we have nailed two issues with camunda which (added together) lead to the Exception from the original question.

1. Camunda uses `equals` on serialized objects (represented by byte-arrays) to determine, whether process variables have to be written back to the database. This even happens when variables are only read and not set. As `equals` is defined by pointer-identity on arrays, a serializabled-Object is never determined "equal" if it has been serialized more than once. We have found, that a single `runtimeService.setVariable()` leads to four db-updates at the time of `completeTask()` (One for setVariable itself, the other three for various camunda-internal validation actions). We think this is a bug and will file a bug report to camunda.
2. Obviously there are two ways to set variables. One way is to use `runtimeService.setVariable()`, the other is to use `delegateTask/delegateExecution.setVariable()`. There is some flaw when using both ways at the same time. While we cannot simplify our setup to a simple unit-test, we have identified several components which have to be involved for the Exception to occur:

2.1 We are using a `TaskListener` to set up some context-variables at the start of Tasks this task-listener used `runtimeService.setVariable()` instead of `delegateTask.setVariable()`. After we changed that, the Exception vanished.

2.2 We used (and still use) `runtimeService.setVariable()` during Task-Execution. After we switched to `completeTask(Variables)` and omitted the `runtimeService.setVariable()` calls, the Exception vanished as well. However, this isn't a permanent solution as we have to store process variables during task execution.

2.3 The exception occured only in combination when process variables where read or written by the `delegate<X>.getVariable()` way (either by our code or implicitly in the camunda implementation of juel-parsing with gateways and serviceTasks or `completeTask(HashMap)`)

Thanks a lot for all your input.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using an asynchronous continuation on the service task. This will make sure that the service task is executed inside a new transaction / command context. 
Consider reading the [camunda documentation on transactions and asynchronous continuations](http://docs.camunda.org/latest/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-transactions-in-processes-transaction-boundaries).

The `DelegateExecution` object is meant for providing service task (`JavaDelegate`) implementations access to process instance variables. It is not meant to be used from a User Task.

Comment: We already have considered this and the fact, that ServiceTask and UserTask are executed in the same transaction is a feature we actually welcome and want to keep. We experimented with the asynchronus continuation and want to stick with the synchronous semantics.

Comment: Yes, you should only add asynchronous continuations if you really need them.